# Milk or water for fluffier scrambled eggs?

Tags: eggs

I used to add milk to eggs when whipping them, but someone told me that water was better since it evaporated and made the eggs fluffier. I've tried it, and I'm not sure which one works better.

Does milk or water make eggs fluffier? Are there other factors changing the fluffiness?

Comment: why would you want scrambled eggs to be fluffy?

Answer (score 34):

If you want slops use the Ramsay method. If you want something with texture and taste try this

Turn the heat onto max and use a light weight pan for gas, or a medium weight pan for electric. Add a small drizzle of oil to the pan

In a strong deep bowl add a splash of milk or water and two eggs (say 20% liquid to 80% egg)

Beat like crazy for 20 seconds (use a whisk or a fork)

When the pan is sizzling pour in the egg mixture and use a medium spatula (a 5cm wide strip of wood is great) fold in the cooked parts as they appear. **Work quickly**

It will begin to form a loose lump in the pan. Keep folding the egg into the lump until all the liquid egg is gone

Optionally add a handful of coarse chopped broad leaf parsley or some thinly sliced cheese just before the final few folds

The cooking phase should have taken **seconds**, not minutes

Remove pan from heat

Let it **rest** for a while before moving so the egg has time to set

The texture is changed from smooth to rough by how often and hard you fold the egg

Comment: Please, may I give this 10 upvotes? Please?

Comment: This is mostly what I do; sometimes I also dash in some Cholula or similar hot sauce while beating the egg.

Comment: Alrighty then - bumped you to 10. This is much more my style than Ramsay's :)

Comment: Is there a video for this cooking method?  Or a picture of the end result?

Comment: The biggest difficulty I had with this was making sure all of the runny stuff ran into the pan. As I got closer to the end, some of the runny stuff didn't want to flow out as I was folding, so it didn't set completely. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Bob That's how it should be. Soft, with texture. The runny stuff does get cooked, it's just not fully set.  This is like a rare steak with a good crust. And if you let it rest, it will firm up more as per your personal preference. Personally I like to deliver to the table an scrambled egg with visible runny bits, to show how fresh it is, and not have it fully cooked, and then maybe fall apart as a series of "egg crumbs" as some places think a scrambled egg should be?

Answer (score 7):

the rule of thumb i've heard is as you say: adding water makes them steam (in effect) and be fluffier, adding milk or cream makes them creamier. the only trick i have for eggs of any sort is to use a low heat, not a high one, and to let them warm up a bit before putting them in the pan, which keeps them from getting rubbery. you could maybe accomplish two things in one stroke by using a tablespoon of warm water when you blend up the eggs.

Comment: Low heat is the way to go and lower the fluffier as long as you tend to the eggs and not let them sit on any side for too long.

Comment: Taking this a step further: I've heard of people adding soda water for even more effect.

Answer (score 4):

Just [look at Ramsay](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dU_B3QNu_Ks) on Youtube.

He cracks the eggs into the pan, adds plenty of butter, and then stirs pretty much continuously until they're just barely done. He even takes the pan off the heat now and then to keep them from cooking too fast. He finishes them with creme fraiche, salt, pepper, and chives.

Comment: I can't repeat often enough: Ramsay's recipe is *disgusting*. It's a way to consistently produce "scrambled" eggs that have all of the bad features and none of the good features of this dish.

Comment: I heard you the first time :)

Comment: I didn't.  @Marti -- What are the bad and good features of which you speak?

Comment: @anon: IMO, scrambled eggs should have body - not tough, but toothsome. They should also taste, well, *eggy*. Ramsay's method produces a slimy, disgusting mess with little to no flavor.

Answer (score 4):

Surprised no one else mentioned this.. my kids like this: 1/2 tsp **ranch dressing** per 2 large eggs.

The resulting egg scramble get more palatable from: attractive flavor tanginess, creamier body, and fluffier composition. Very simple, and no other ingredients required :)

And, if you're looking for even fluffier, you could add 1/2 tsp water on top of that, as well. The issue I have with water is if you forget to take it off right after the mix is done cooking, it can leech the water back out. It's less likely to happen on a lower heat, but sometimes in the breakfast rush. I also like to top with a moderate amount of mild cheddad for kids, or pepper jack for me. One of my kids likes ketchup with the ranch scramble, too - but he's a freak, so I don't recommend trying that unless you are as well =P

Answer (score 3):

I can't really tell why, but the perfect recipe seems to use some water: Add some water along with the raw eggs into the pan and constantly stir it until you get the consistency you like. The water prevents the mass from becoming too dry or even stick to the pan. Also this way you have more time to control the consistency since it takes longer to become ready. The water will mostly vaporize (if you don't add too much) and not make a mess out of your scrambled eggs.

Comment: Btw. I first prepare some diced onions in the pan using butter (better than oil). After that I add the eggs and some water and salt. When it's done I pour it onto the dish, grind some fresh pepper onto it and eat it together with bread & butter. Hmmm.

Answer (score 3):

My secret is lots of butter. Put a generous lump of it in the pan, and melt, then add the beaten eggs, milk/water, seasoning, whatever else you are putting in (I often add parsley, chives, grated cheese), and then beat and heat gently until almost at the consistency you want. It's personal choice really - some people love their eggs runny, others like them almost dry. I'm somewhere in between, but if you serve just before they get perfect, they finish themselves off with the heat they have in them.

Serve with buttery toast - cut into soldiers for kids!

Answer (score 3):

The salt should not touch the eggs until the very end, it solidifies the proteins and makes 'tough' eggs which release their water content, don't believe me? try next time you make whatever recipe you prefer but leave the salt out till the last strokes.

Answer (score 0):

"Adding 1 tablespoon of water for every egg results in a lighter texture. Adding the same amount of milk or heavy cream will have the same effect, except that the fat level of the milk or cream also influences the creaminess of the eggs."

From [this article](http://www.sj-r.com/features/x933815964/Scrambled-eggs-the-perfect-recipe).