# What are the reasons for using an egg whisk to cook scrambled eggs?

Tags: equipment, scrambled-eggs

When cooking scrambled eggs in the frypan I use a spatula to gather the egg together. To me this doesn't damage the pan, and avoids the egg forming 'nodules'. It also saves the time-consuming hassle of cleaning cooked egg off the egg whisk, and possibly saves the hygiene risk of not properly cleaning all of the egg off the egg whisk.

Now I could be completely wrong or have missed something. I know of people who are strongly in favour of using an egg whisk to cook scrambled eggs.

My question is: **What are the reasons for using an egg whisk to cook scrambled eggs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, like [several questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49944/science-of-fast-high-heat-vs-slow-low-heat-scrambled-eggs-and-omelets?rq=1) on [this site](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7405/69341) about scrambled eggs, this comes down to ones preferred curd size. There are many different ways of making scrambled eggs: at one extreme one heats very slowly, stirring gently with a spatula, and getting very large curds. Some people say this gives a [sloppy texture](https://www.discusscooking.com/forums/f17/do-you-prefer-custardy-or-fluffy-scrambled-eggs-105424.html), others prefer the smooth mouth feel. At the other extreme, one heats quickly and whisks, breaking up the curds entirely, and giving a fluffy mousse like texture.