# Gravy with Scrambled Eggs :: What went wrong?

Tags: gravy, scrambled-eggs

OK, I love scrambled eggs but I wanted a variant which isn't completely dry so here is what I did:
I got some instant (add hot water) type gravy packets which were of Chinese cuisine. I added hot water and stirred like crazy till it tasted, looked and had a good consistency like gravy. I made my scrambled eggs [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/8973/9141) way and simply added them. As a consequence, the scrambled eggs got all soggy and tasted really weird. 
The ratio of addition was just enough to drown the scrambled eggs. Sorry but I can't provide metric proportions

Note: I am on a student budget, please suggest improvements which won't burn holes in my pockets.

Comment: Can you add the egg to gravy ratio that you used?

Comment: Oh I see. You added the gravy on top of the finished egg product. I misunderstood and thought you used the gravy in place of the milk/water to make the eggs. If you are just putting the gravy on top, why don't you just use less gravy?

Comment: It taste "weird". As if something is really really wrong. The gravy seems too strong for its taste. I tried using a dilute mixture and even lesser gravy but the taste is still fairly strong.

Comment: Why don't you just try something different on top, like salsa or something?

Comment: Did you ever tried that gravy before (without eggs)? How did that taste?

Comment: It tastes OK. I tried adding boiled cauliflower and it was fairly eatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instant gravy packets are not known for their subtle flavor. They contain boullion, tons of salt, and some modified starch. If you don't like the flavor of a lot of that gravy then don't use it.

The scrambled egg recipe that you linked to is of a particular variety. They are just barely set. This gives them a very delicate flavor and even more delicate texture. They are also as moist as scrambled eggs can be.

Such a preparation of eggs would not be well served by a gravy.

My suggestions are these:
1- Use a different recipe for your eggs that will cook them much more. If you insist on a gravy then your eggs will need to have the structure enough to support it.

2- Make your own gravy and don't ever use those packets again- even if you are starving to death I think they would only hasten your demise. Instead find a recipe for a quick white sauce- (just fat, flour, and milk). If you would like you can add a little shredded cheese for flavor. I think you will find this will be more satisfying and possibly even less expensive than your gravy-packet-crimes-against-humanity.

Comment: "...even if you are starving to death I think they would only hasten your demise..." Hehe. OK. Thanks. Egg + Alfredo sauce? I'm a little concerned about the taste of this combination.

Comment: @Nunoxic, I've never really heard of sauce/gravy over top of scrambled eggs. Why don't you try sauce over top of easy over eggs?

Comment: Alfredo sauce would be fantastic (basically butter, cream, and cheese- All of which love eggs)- especially if you make your eggs a little firmer to hold it up. Incidentally- it is conventional to wait a little bit before accepting an answer to see if anything better comes along.

Comment: @Nunonix Actually that's Mornay sauce. I think it would be pretty good. It won't be as heavy as alfredo since there is less fat, and more of a subtle cheese flavor. :)

Comment: @Max Mornay sauce. Must investigate. Sobachatina, I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: @Max Is it? Mornay is béchamel plus cheese, and béchamel is milk and roux. Flour, butter, milk and cheese.

Comment: @Jefromi, indeed. I was remarking on Nunonixs comment 'egg + alfredo sauce'. It seems to me that Sobachatina's 'white sauce' with shredded cheese is called Mornay and not Alfredo sauce, which is what I was trying to tell Nunonix. It's entirely possible I've misunderstood something now though! Alfredo to me is thickened with cream, not flour...

Answer (score -1):

fry the eggs separately  and then add the gravy

Comment: In my understanding, this is exactly what the OP did, and was not happy with the result - which is understandable, since it results in drowning the eggs in a liquid with not necessarily compatible flavor.

Answer (score -1):

I just made scrambled using the left over gravy we added to the slow cooker for dinner this evening
I fried the egg in the gravy and it was damn near heavenly.  It reminded me of adding lawreys seasond salt to eggs just more moist with hints of brow gravy.

Comment: It would help to know a little more about the nature of your gravy. If you were able to use it as a frying medium, I'm imagining something very greasy.