# Making a pocket-type french omelette without the curd sticking to the pan?

Tags: french-cuisine, omelette

I'm trying to make the pocket/rugby-ball shaped type of omelette, basically the second omelette in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s10etP1p2bU . I want it to be runny on the inside and untorn on the outside.

I also use chopsticks instead of a fork because I saw advice to use them for this recipe, chopsticks being less harsh on the nonstick coating, and better for mixing everything up in the pan.

The problem is, when I come to the shake-and-stir bit, where the heat of the liquid should rise relatively evenly, instead I get a sticky curd on the pan, which is also difficult to move around because it's too dry and even if I leave more liquid around to curd with it, it doesn't cohere.

Anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong here? Is the pan too hot/cold? Am I using too little butter? Are chopsticks the wrong tool for the job? Or is it really more about technique?

Comment: The heat is probably to high; or your non-stick pan is old and does not work as expected; remember, Pepin is a pro.

Comment: He is, I'm just hoping this specific technique is simple enough for me to get right.

Comment: You simply need practice; he knows his pan, he knows the heat of the burner,... Also, maybe his eggs are not too cold either; get them out of the fridge 1/2 before using them.

Comment: BTW, I suck at making omelette; they either burn or are too soft or too much butter (turned in to scrambled eggs) or get chewie.

Comment: I used a spatula when I did my tests for 'omurice' : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/53962/67 .  (specifically I used a metal spatula as I was cooking on anodized aluminum, not teflon.  If you're using teflon, you might want to use a silicone spatula).  And check out the video in the omurice question, as you might realize some improvements on your technique.

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks for the link. Would you say that the utensil used had little effect on the result? That is, would you recommend using a spatula instead of chopsticks?

Comment: I find that butter and higher heat than you'd expect are key. I use a silicone spatula and a well-used Element B iron pan. Get the pan hot, then add a generous knob of butter. I've tried with other fats, but butter has consistently been the best.

Answer (score 2):

Start with examining your pan closely.
I suspect Pepin's has a good base with even heat distribution (no heat spots) and a good working non stick surface.
Also consider using a wooden spoon/spatula or non stick compliant tool, as you might not be moving the curds quickly enough.

Without pictures or detail, your pan temperature and amount of butter can't be advised.  BTW, it is known as a (French) "Classic Omelette"

Comment: Temperature will probably be difficult to figure out remotely, but how much butter would you consider "right"? Or is it pan-dependant?

Comment: You can gauge temperature by hovering your hand over the pan, this will help you gauge the temperature of the pan.  Note, if you have a gas hob and the flame is licking up the pan than this may give you a false reading (flame is probably too high if you do, apart from wasting energy).  Also when you add your oil/butter you can see and possibly hear how hot the pan is.  How quickly it melts, sizzles, or moves round the pan.  If you remember the video the butter melted relatively quickly, and was ready when all of the butter foamed/bubbled.

Comment: Butter can be pan dependent, but using Pepin's video (as an example of a good pan) enough foaming butter to cover the base of the pan.  Additional butter was added near the end to add more taste and help finish the omelette.