# What is the term for 'sunny side up' omelette?

Tags: eggs, language, omelette, scrambled-eggs

I have a technique when cooking omlettes where you only cook them on one side, and gather up the edges - but let the cheese accumulate in the soft centre.

Friends have suggested several names for this:

- scramelette
- sunny side up omelette
- soft-centred omelette

The thought occurs that there must be a canonical name - which I'd like to know so I can order it at a restaurant.

My question is: **What is the term for 'sunny side up' omelette?**

Comment: French omelettes are usually cooked only on one side then folded

Comment: And there's also the Japanese omelette, but that likely won't have cheese.  (and would qualify as a 'soft-centred omelette', but maybe not 'sunny side up', as you scramble it while it cooks at first : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/53962/67

Comment: Your creation is what I always think of when someone says 'omelette' without any qualifier.

Comment: Thanks @canardgras - I'm used to 'sunny side down' omelettes being the default - but agree with you. Sunny side up is the best!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that is called a classic french omelette.
"Sunnyside" comes from frying unbroken eggs, where the yolk resembles the sun, and by not flipping the egg over makes it "Sunnyside up".